# How to type "@" on a Macbook 2.1

Tags: keyboard, macintosh, macbook

I have set the keyboard layout to "Macintosh".

On a Macbook Pro I can use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to get a `@` but the Macbook 2.1 doesn't have a right Alt key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to System Settings
2. Choose Keyboard
3. And activate "Left Alt" as "Key to choose 3rd level" in the Options Tab

[image]

Comment: What does this do, on the software level?