# Keyboard custom settings in Loki 0.4.1

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to solve the problem on [How to type @ on a MacBookPro 2.1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/376/how-to-type-on-a-macbook-2-1) but Keyboard in settings doesn't show an Options button like pictured on the screenshot.

What workaround is there to this issue?

Comment: Does the option exist under Keyboard -> Layout -> key to choose 3rd level?

Comment: There is that option, but no left alt choice, so I used 'cap locks' + 2 (I'm on a Belgian keyboard on that machine). It produces @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Loki 0.4.1 to enable to type @ on a MacbookPro 2,1 in *Keyboard -> Layout -> key to choose 3rd level*'s choices did not include '*left alt*', then the issue can be solved attributing it to '*caps lock*', providing I'm using the GUI a lot I'm not using 'caps lock' frequently at all, so it's a working choice.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to put it on Left-Alt like this:
open terminal and put:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

An setup starts with a Keyboard-configuration, the 4th screen is the 3rd-level option for me, I was able to choose left Alt here (not on a Macbook)
Finish the setup than put:

```
service keyboard-setup restart
```

And it should work!

PS: Sometimes this change isn't permanent (gone at restart), write back if that's the case.